# Lua to 'C' calling convention issues

Tags: lua

I don't really want to go down the metatables etc. route as it seems rather complicated.
To crudely access 'C' structs in Lua I do:

```
void execute_lua_script(char *name)
{
    lua_pushstring (L,name);
    lua_gettable (L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX); 
    lua_pushstring(L,"junk");
    lua_pushinteger(L,7);
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, avatar_obj);
    lua_pcall (L, 3, 2, 0);
}
```

The registered C func is:

```
int get_obj_struct(lua_State *L)
{
    const char *str;
    OBJECT_DEF *obj;
    int stack;

    obj=(OBJECT_DEF *)lua_touserdata(L,1);

    str=lua_tostring(L,2);

    //printf("\nIN OBJ:%d %s",obj,str);

    if (!strcmp(str,"body->p.x"))
        lua_pushnumber(L,obj->body->p.x);

    if (!strcmp(str,"collided_with"))
        lua_pushlightuserdata(L, obj->collided_with);

    if (!strcmp(str,"type"))
        lua_pushnumber(L,obj->type);

    stack=lua_gettop(L);
    //printf("\n%d",stack);

    if (stack<3)
        report_error("Unknown structure request ",(char *)str);

    return 1;
}
```

Although crude; it works! :-)
The problem is when I request "collided_with" (a pointer); I need to return that back to my script; but for reasons I don't understand 'obj' ends up as nil.

My lua script:

```
function test(a,b,obj)
    --print("\nLUA! test:",a,b);

    b=b+1;

    c=get_obj_struct(obj,"body->p.x");

    --print("x:",c);

    collided_with=get_obj_struct(obj,"collided_with");
    type=get_obj_struct(collided_with,"type");

    print("type:",type);

    return a,b;
end
```

I am expecting 'collided_with' to be a pointer that I can then pass back into get_obj_struct and look for type.
I know it's something to do with me mis-using pushlightuserdata and also reading for the obj.
So an explanation would be great!. Also if someone wishes to give a version that uses 'tables' (as I assume that would be much more efficient) then I would be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The online "[Programming In Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/)" book provides a good description of how to implement Lua types in C. In my opinion, your best bet would be to follow the examples provided in [Chapter 28](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.html) to "do it right" and create a complete Lua wrapper for your object. In addition to being easier to maintain, it will almost certainly be more faster than a `strcmp` based implementation.